# VueJS - extending Webpack 5 to ignore url paths in SCSS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm probably off the mark here, but I have some SCSS files with invalid URL paths, which is expected as they exist on the server but not localhost.  I'm trying to get webpack to ignore and lines specifying a URL, like so:

`background: url('/content/images/icons/play.svg') no-repeat;`

As I said, I'm probably off a ways but this is where I'm at, clearly not in a working state...

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('scss')
      .test(/\.scss$/)
      .use('vue-style-loader','css-loader',)
      .loader('css-loader')
      .tap(() => {
        return {
          url: false
        }
      })
  }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated...